# Cant reading from file in nativescrypt

Tags: telerik, readfile, nativescript

I trying write some strings in file and then read them, but having error message **Cannot access a locked file.** Tested on iphone and android.

## page.xml

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded" actionBarHidden="true">
<StackLayout>
<Label text="Tap the button" id="label"/>
<Button text="TAP" id="btn" />
</StackLayout>
</Page>
```

## page.js

```
var frameModule = require("ui/frame");
var view = require("ui/core/view");
var dialogs = require("ui/dialogs");
var fs = require("file-system");

function pageLoaded(args) {
   var page = args.object;

   var button = view.getViewById(page, "btn");
   var label = view.getViewById(page, "label");

   button.on("tap", function (){
        var documents = fs.knownFolders.documents();
        var myFile = documents.getFile("Test_Write.txt");

   myFile.writeText("Something")
        .then(function () {
        myFile.readText()
            .then(function (content) {
            label.text = content;

        }, function (error) {
            label.text = error;
        });
    }, function (error) {
        label.text = error;
    });
   });
}
   exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `write` methods lock but never unlock the file.

[This has been addressed with the following pull request](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/1081).